# Is there an existing name for a government type like this?

Tags: society, government, politics

This government type probably exists already, and I just can't find it anywhere. I've been roaming this site for a while, so I figure I'd ask a short question of my own; is there a government type which is like democracy, but medical professionals are the only ones who can be elected (Ex. Surgeons, ER doctors, pediatricians, etc.)? Don't mistake this for Geniocracy, in which those above a certain IQ can rule and vote. Regular people can vote in this, but only the top medical professionals are allowed to run for office.

Comment: "Medical meritocracy"?

Comment: @cowlinator I think that's it, yeah. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Medical Meritocracy**

A meritocracy is a government ruled by people selected on the basis of their ability or education.

Answer (score 1):

That's a technocracy, but for medical professionals specifically.